# clone my ubuntu from hdd to new ssd related question

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I have resize the HDD partitions with Gparted Live and copy the reduced-size partitions(only file system on it) to the smaller SSD with Clonezilla live , and both of them are successful already.now I try to use the boot partition(dev/sda1) on HDD to boot my SSD system, and is it correct?

Comment: I remove the HDD but the SSD can't be booted, I haven't install the boot partition on SSD, should I do that?

Comment: can I directly copy the boot/efi file on HDD to SDD, use cp command?

Comment: EFI may be complicating things... did you copy the EFI boot partition along with the data partition? That may have been easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that your drive is copied to the new media, before removing the original drive you need to download and burn this [boot repair cd](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/).  After swapping out your old and new hard drives you will need to boot to this CD and let it configure your new drive to boot your system.

If you do not disconnect the original hard drive, the Boot Repair CDrom will not be able to prepare the SSD as your boot device.  If at a later time you wish to reconnect your HDD or format it as free space, I'd be happy to help you with that, but first we must complete this step.

Comment: I already download the boot repair and it works. Boot successfully repaired, the following URL:http://paste.ubuntu.com/9671442. I got two choice,ubuntu14.04(should be HDD) and ubuntu14.04(/dev/sdb1)(it's ssd, sure be that.),  when I chose the second, I entry the system , but I realize it is still the HDD system

Comment: I foresaw this difficulty and thought I made myself clear.  I've added a second paragraph to my answer to help you understand what you must do.

Comment: Boot-Repair can easily run from any live Ubuntu, or Debian-based distro, no need for a whole disk just for it. That's even the Boot-Repair recommended way to get it: *"Recommended: boot on a Debian (or derivatives: Ubuntu, Linux Mint...) disk, either normal session, or live-CD, or live-USB. Then install Boot-Repair in it, either via PPA for Ubuntu/Mint, or DEBs for Debian."*

Comment: @Xen2050, if boot repair is being included in live ubuntu disks this is news to me.  Happy news actually, but nonetheless news I was until now unaware of.  Are you certain of this?

Comment: Not included by default, but installable like the quote says. The info was from the link you pasted, on the main Boot-Repair page http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ with the PPA link going here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @gyropyge , I have boot my SSD successful with your suggestion,thanks. now, when I input 'fdisk -l' on command line,it shows 'WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.what effects does it have?

Comment: @wind, I've been using Ubuntu for 9 years and from day one I fell in love with gparted.  I had never dreamed of a more perfect disk partitioning tool.  It is one of the first features of Ubuntu I tell other geeks about.  So, having said all of that, I've never run into this problem before.  What I don't understand is how, if you cloned your entire hard drive to the SSD, how could it be possible that the partitioning scheme changed?  The new drive should be identical to the old drive, unless you used some really dishonest disk cloning tool.

Comment: @gyropyge,I didn't clone the entire hard drive to the SSD,just one partition that file system on it. And I chose the SSD partition's type was GPT

Comment: @wind, I'm sorry to hear that.  Unless there is a clear and easy way to fix this, my solution would be to CLONE the entire original hard drive to the new drive, leaving the file system intact otherwise, at least as far as partitioning scheme.  If the new drive is of smaller capacity, then you may need to resize the partitions on the original drive, and shift them to the left to resemble a total size smaller than the destination drive.  One more tip, I advise making the total size about 500mb smaller than the destination drive. Clonezilla should reproduce partitioning accurately.

Answer (score 1):

**dd** command should works.

```
dd if=[Input file or Device] of=[Output file or Device] bs=[Byte Per Seconds]

dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4m
```

where sda is for old hard disk and sdb is your new SSD.

dd command copy byte by byte from an storage to new storage.

Comment: The drives aren't the same size, the new one's smaller

Comment: So you should Copy Partition to new partition and make ssd bootable.

Comment: That's what wind's trying... How?

Comment: "dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4m" sda1 is source partition and sdb1 is destination partition. Attention! double check your command. It's dangerous.

Comment: I think dd command not be worked,you can resize the partition on HDD first with the tools named Gparted live USB/CD , it's easy to use. And then you can use the clonezilla live USB/CD to clone the file system from HDD to SSD , I just did that. finally, set the boot partition on SSD , it's ok.

Comment: wind, Clonezilla is DD but faster! why, cause clonezilla knows the file system and can skip empty spaces but dd copy sector to sector. so both will work. I prefer dd :)

Comment: if sda1 partition is 400G , and the sdb1 is 120G,does DD still work?

Comment: No, for all partition just work for first 120G.

Comment: I have 1TB HDD. And I only have used total around 20GB.
If I copy with DD first 50GB from HDD to SSD.
will it work?
Or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you ran clonezilla, you also cloned your /etc/fstab file so that it you boot off the ssd, the fstab there tells linux that the / and /home (if separate partitions) are looking to the spinning HD. You just neet to change /etc/fstab on sdb to to have the UUID of the ssd.

You can test it like so...

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Be sure you are on your ssd and comment out the line that has / right after the UUID by putting a # at the start of the line. Create a net line below it with everythig the same, except change the UUID to the one of your SSD.

<kbd>alt</kbd>-o <kbd>alt</kbd>-x  Will save and exit (letter o not number) 
reboot and check it out.

Comment: why I don't feel faster than HDD when installed SSD, though the startup machine time seems get a little speed

Comment: If you are haven't changed the fstab, you are using the hdd right after the ssd starts to boot. The ssd is handing off the majority of boot to the hdd.

Comment: I only use the SSD on my laptop,I can feel the startup time is faster, but the time of titanium build is still so slow, some suggestions?